# How to bind a RelayCommand(MVVM) to a RoutedCommand? (CommandBinding)

Tags: wpf, relaycommand, routed-commands

I want to create a custom class of a CommandBinding, where a RelayCommand of my ViewModel is executed when the RoutedCommand is executed.

Currently there is only the possibility to create CommandBindings which have Executed methods in the codebehind class. 
Example:

```
   <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" Executed="CloseCommandHandler"
                CanExecute="CanExecuteHandler"/>
```

This needs the CloseCommandHandler methode in the code behind.

I would want to write the following.

```
   <CommandBinding RoutedCommand="ApplicationCommands.Close" Command={Binding Path=CloseCommand}/>
```

The only problem is that i can't find the bubble down and up event of the RoutedCommands.
There is no

```
OnPreviewCommand(object command, object commandParammeter)
OnCommand(object command, object commandParammeter)
```

Where is the RoutedCommand bubble down and up handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solutions of my own. Its not the most beautiful, but its working.

I derived from the ContentControl. The new Control has a RoutedCommandBindings property, which contains a list of "sort of" CommandBindings between RoutedCommands and RelayCommands.

It can be used like this.

```
<CSControls:RoutedCommandBinder>
   <CSControls:RoutedCommandBinder.RoutedCommandBindings>
      <CSControls:RoutedCommandBindingCollection>
         <CSControls:RoutedCommandBinding RoutedCommand="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.New}" Command="{Binding Path=AddInstanceCommand}"/>
      </CSControls:RoutedCommandBindingCollection>
   </CSControls:RoutedCommandBinder.RoutedCommandBindings>
   <CSControls:RoutedCommandBinder.Content>
      <!-- Every RoutedCommand of type ApplicationCommands.New will execute the binded RelayCommand "AddInstanceCommand-->
   </CSControls:RoutedCommandBinder.Content>
</CSControls:RoutedCommandBinder>
```

Here is the CustomControl code.

```
public class RoutedCommandBinder : ContentControl
{
    public RoutedCommandBinder()
    {
        this.DataContextChanged += RoutedCommandBinder_DataContextChanged;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RoutedCommandBindingsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RoutedCommandBindings", typeof(RoutedCommandBindingCollection), typeof(RoutedCommandBinder), new PropertyMetadata(new RoutedCommandBindingCollection(), OnRoutedCommandBindingsChanged));
    public RoutedCommandBindingCollection RoutedCommandBindings
    {
        get { return (RoutedCommandBindingCollection)this.GetValue(RoutedCommandBindingsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RoutedCommandBindingsProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnRoutedCommandBindingsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RoutedCommandBinder binder = (RoutedCommandBinder)d;
        binder.CommandBindings.Clear();
        SetDataContextForCommandBindings(binder);
        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            RoutedCommandBindingCollection bindings = (RoutedCommandBindingCollection)e.NewValue;
            foreach (RoutedCommandBinding binding in bindings)
            {
                binder.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(binding.RoutedCommand, binder.RoutedCommandExecuted, binder.CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler));
            }
        }
    }

    private void RoutedCommandBinder_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetDataContextForCommandBindings(this);
    }

    private static void SetDataContextForCommandBindings(RoutedCommandBinder binder)
    {
        if (binder.DataContext != null && binder.RoutedCommandBindings != null)
        {
            foreach (RoutedCommandBinding binding in binder.RoutedCommandBindings)
            {
                binding.DataContext = binder.DataContext;
            }
        }
    }

    private void RoutedCommandExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RoutedCommandBinding binding = this.RoutedCommandBindings.FirstOrDefault(t => t.RoutedCommand == e.Command);
        if (binding != null)
        {
            binding.Command.Execute(e.Parameter);
        }
    }

    private void CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RoutedCommandBinding binding = this.RoutedCommandBindings.FirstOrDefault(t => t.RoutedCommand == e.Command);
        if (binding != null)
        {
            e.CanExecute = binding.Command.CanExecute(e.Parameter);
        }
    }
}

public class RoutedCommandBindingCollection : List<RoutedCommandBinding>
{ 
}

public class RoutedCommandBinding : FrameworkElement
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(RoutedCommandBinding), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)this.GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RoutedCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RoutedCommand", typeof(RoutedCommand), typeof(RoutedCommandBinding), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public RoutedCommand RoutedCommand
    {
        get { return (RoutedCommand)this.GetValue(RoutedCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RoutedCommandProperty, value); }
    }
}
```